# Postgres data backup/export to Azure Blob storage using Azure function

Tags: postgresql, azure-functions, backup, npgsql, azure-blob-storage

I need to do an automatic periodic backup of specific Postgres table to Azure blob storage.
I am using "Azure database for Postgres" as database. 
In that, I was having one table with millions of timeseries data. So, I have partitioned data day wise.
Now, I want to keep only last few days partitions and detach & drop older partitions after backing up on Azure blob storage.

For normal database operation I am using azure functions written in C# (using NPgsql nuget package).
**Is there any way to performing backup/export programmatically?**
I did some research but couldn't find any automated way. Even, Azure data migration service is not supporting postgres data backup on blob storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend exploring non-programmatic ways of doing full-database backup rather than attempting to do this programmatically. While PostgreSQL has pg_backup, which can be very easily be scripted to run periodically and have its output uploaded to blob storage, there's no built-in facility for doing this programmatically.

Otherwise you could look at exporting specific tables via Npgsql's [bulk copy API](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html), but that's not meant for full-database backup.

Comment: Completed my task using bulk copy API. Thanks. @Shay Rojansky